# Регулярка для парсинга цены

Tags: регулярные-выражения

есть такая регулярка: `\d[\s\d.,]+руб`

Парсит более менее адекватно, но есть случаи, когда в тексте может быть такое

> ***12.31.2002, 66647814 руб***

То есть в начале дата и после запятой цена, а парсит он все, как это обойти?

И опишу на всякий случай, какие могут быть виды цен:

> 66647814 руб.
>
> 123.166.499,81 руб
>
> 166.499 руб
>
> 166 499 руб
>
> 23 499,80 руб

То есть в конце всегда будет "**руб**", от этого как то можно отталкиваться

Comment: [`(?:\d+(?:[\s.,]\d+)?)+ руб`](https://regex101.com/r/JSqvx3/1)

Comment: `\d+(?:[,. ]\d+)*?\sруб`

Answer (score 0):

Суть обработки запятой - она допустима в числе только перед копейками

```
\d[\d\s\.]*(?:,\d{1,2})?\sруб
```

Пример на [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/H5rG6w/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+(?:[ \.]\d{3})*(?:,\d+)* руб

\d+ - несколько цифр
(?:[ \.]\d{3})* - возможно несколько классов, разделенных пробелом или запятой
(?:,\d+) - возможно дробная часть
```

[demo на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DMjeZv/1)